# How to check for which country a youtube video is allowed?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For some videos, YouTube site would say, **Video not available in my country**.
Is it possible to check using YouTube data APIs or some other way, which country this particular video is allowed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties). You can use the `contentDetails.regionRestriction` property of the video.

Example : `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=tDDAa1If-u4&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Answer (score 8):

This site will provide information about the countries the video is restricted.

https://polsy.org.uk/stuff/ytrestrict.cgi

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Any relevant information from the link should be summarized within your answer.